# php gd text break on image

Tags: php, html, gd, gdi

i am trying to break a long phrase depending on my skyscraper banner width size which  can not afford more than three words, i searched the internet and found a script which break the text by setting the character long for the phrase, here is it.

```
<?

header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['text']. '  Click Here';
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("../../images/skyscrapper.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 3.8 * strlen($string)) / 2;
$font = 'verdana.ttf';

// Break it up into pieces 10 characters long
$lines = explode('|', wordwrap($string, 10, '|'));

// Starting Y position
$y = 450;

// Loop through the lines and place them on the image
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
imagestring($im,3, $px, $y, $string, $orange);

    // Increment Y so the next line is below the previous line
    $y += 23;
}

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);



?>
```

the problem is the output duplicate the phrase three times instead breaking the text as this screen shot[image: text keeps duplicated]
, can someone help to explain whats the problem and what should i do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not changing `$string` inside your loop. Shouldn't it be:

```
imagestring($im,3, $px, $y, $line, $orange);
                            ^^^^^
```

instead?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe replace

```
imagestring($im,3, $px, $y, $string, $orange);
```

with

```
imagestring($im,3, $px, $y, $line, $orange);
```